# How to use std::for_each on a map element method with input?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have:

```
struct Mystruct
{
    void Update(float Delta);
}

typedef std::map<int, Mystruct*> TheMap;
typedef TheMap::iterator         TheMapIt;

TheMap Container;
```

and wants to do:

```
for(TheMapIt It = Container.begin(), Ite = Container.end(); It != Ite; ++It)
{
    It->second->Update(Delta);
}
```

using `std::for_each`, how to do this?

I think I can declare function like:

```
void Do(const std::pair<int, Mystruct*> Elem)
{
    Elem->Update(/*problem!*/); ---> How to pass Delta in?
}
```

Or make another struct:

```
struct Doer
{
    Doer(float Delta): d(Delta) {}

    void operator(std::pair<int, Mystruct*> Elem)
    {
        Elem->Update(d);
    }
}
```

But this requires a new struct.

What I wants to achieve is using plain `std::for_each` with something like `std::bind_1st`, `std::mem_fun` like the way with `std::vector`, is it possible?

Please consider using `std` way before using `boost`, thanks!

I've referenced this but it doesnt metion about member function with input...
[How would I use for_each to delete every value in an STL map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463528/how-would-i-use-for-each-to-delete-every-value-in-an-stl-map)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a trade between coding style, for loop and for_each doesn't make big difference, below are two other approaches besides for loop:

If you use C++11, could try lambda:

```
std::for_each(TheMap.begin(), TheMap.end(), 
              [](std::pair<int, Mystruct*>& n){ n.second->Update(1.0); });
```

Or in C++03, you could add a member function to wrapper class then call `std::bind1st` and `std::mem_fun`

```
struct MapWrapper
{
  MapWrapper(int value=1.0):new_value(value) {}

  void Update(std::pair<int, Mystruct*> map_pair)
  {
    map_pair.second->Update(new_value);
  }
  void setValue(float value) { new_value = value; }
  float new_value;
  std::map<int, Mystruct*> TheMap;
};

MapWrapper wrapper;
wrapper.setvalue(2.0);
std::for_each(wrapper.TheMap.begin(), 
              wrapper.TheMap.end(),std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&MapWrapper::Update), &wrapper));
```

Write a functor isn't a bad choice, why you are against it? A functor provides better design as it provides clean and clear purpose.

```
struct Doer
{
    Doer(float Delta): d(Delta) {}

    void operator()(std::pair<int, Mystruct*> e)
    {
      e.second->Update(d);
    }
    float d;
};
Doer doer(1.0);
std::for_each(wrapper.TheMap.begin(), wrapper.TheMap.end(), doer);
```

Comment: Hi: that 1.0 cant be const, it must be passed in. And I dont want to make new classes for this task. Is it possible? Thanks :)

Comment: for_each 3rd argument is Unary function which means it can't take extra argument. You could add member function to MapWrapper to set value dynamically? see my updated answer.

Comment: I'd go with `struct Doer` it's a better choice.

Comment: You can use `std::bind1st` to deal with binary function, but I just donw know how to take care of `map` element, since it is not `vector`. I know how to use `std::bind1st` on `(*it)->update(Delta)`, but it is `(*it).second->update(Delta)` now. :(

Comment: I would just like to point out that `TheMap` is a typename, and the instance is named `Container`.

Comment: You should write `[](std::pair<const int, Mystruct*>& n){ n.second->Update(1.0); }`, i.e., `const int` instead of `int` I believe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260470/error-with-for-each-map-and-lambda-when-passing-by-non-auto-non-const-lvalue-re

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to point out the lambda can be written with nicer syntax, which you've already started down this road by defining a typedef for your map.  The next step is to use ValueType so you don't have to remember that map elements are std::pairs, and also to avoid having to write out the template arguments.

```
 using namespace std;
 for_each(begin(Container), end(Container), 
          [](TheMap::ValueType& n){ n.second->Update(1.0); });
```

Much easier to read, and lets you change some details without necessarily having to propagate those changes a ton of different places.