# Error with for_each, map and lambda when passing by non-auto non-const lvalue reference

Tags: c++, lambda, foreach, reference, auto

In the following code, the first `for_each` statement gives me errors with GCC 7.2, some of which says:

> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::pair&' to an rvalue of type 'std::pair'

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::map<int, double> m = { {1, 1.0}, {2, 2.0}, {3, 3.0} };

  std::for_each(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
                [](std::pair<int, double>& e){ e.second += 1.0; }); // ERROR

  std::for_each(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
                [](auto& e){ e.second += 1.0; }); // OK

  for (auto iter = std::begin(m); iter != std::end(m); ++iter)
    iter->second += 1.0;

  for (auto & e : m)
    e.second += 1.0;

  for (auto & [ key, value ] : m)
    value += 1.0;

  std::cout << m[1] << ", " << m[2] << ", " << m[3] << std::endl;
}
```

What causes this error? How's that it works with `auto`, i.e., in the second `for_each` statement?

According to this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14037863/580083 the first `for_each` should work (and I've also found another answer that said the very same).

Online code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/mOUS1NMjKooetnN1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify key of a `std::map`, so you should use

```
  std::for_each(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
            [](std::pair<const int, double>& e){ e.second += 1.0; });
```

Comment: See also [`value_type`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: @DanielLangr dont blindly trust answers, especially when they say "you could try this..." ;)

Comment: @DanielLangr Check the comments below the answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
  std::for_each(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
            [](std::pair<const int, double>& e){ e.second += 1.0; });
```

It is crucial to declare `Key` element of pair as `const`. See the `value_type` member type in `std::map` [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

In your next line `auto` works, because it automatically declares `Key` as `const`.